# Changing of stored list value

Tags: python

Hi can someone please explain to me why this function isn't working as I intended it to?  I know I can do it by using the index of the list to check if the element is equal to a variable but why can't this method work?

Expectations- I wanted this function to change the element in list (`stored`) if it matches a particular value. IE chance letter `c` to the `#` symbol in this example.

Results - The list (`stored`) that is printed will have no difference and end up print `[a,b,c,d,e]`

Code

```
stored = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
def if_match():
  for letters in stored:
    if letters == "c":
      letters = "#"
  print stored
```

Comment: This isn’t valid python. Are you actually capitalizing the keywords `def`, `if` and `for`?

Comment: Sorry its because i typed the code on my phone. How do i post it in code format?

Comment: I gave an edit to my answer, you can refer it.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because `letters` is a variable used just to iterate over the list. To actually change the value you need to do:

```
for x in range(len(stored)):
    if stored[x] == "c":
        stored[x] = "#"
```

Or you can enumerate through the list like this:

```
for index, value in enumerate(stored):
    if value == "c":
        stored[index] = "#"
```

This will actually change the value of `"c"` to `"#"`.

Comment: Doesnt letters refer to each variable in the list ? So when that particular variable is equal to what i am checking it against i change the value of the variable?

Comment: @YeoBryan it changes the value of the variable, but not the value present in the list

Comment: @YeoBryan please accept my answer if it helped you

Comment: It is not a copy.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga can you please provide clarification as to why

Comment: Because it is not a copy. Put some mutable object in a list, iterate over the list, mutate the object, and you will see it is not a copy

Comment: The keys point: assignment never mutates

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga so why doesn't changing the value of the variable letters change the value inside the list

Comment: Because *assignment never mutates*

Comment: stored = [ "a","b","c","d","e"]
    n=0
    for i in range(5):
      if stored[n] == "c":
        stored[n] = "#"
        n+=1
      else:
        n+=1
    print stored
 But for this code it works? Sorry but i am not rly sure why thats the case

Comment: @YeoBryan Use proper formatting for your comment. I don't realy understand what you mean. Also, if this works, make sure you accept it